# Which are the best tools for nodejs TDD/BDD?

Tags: node.js, tdd, bdd

I developed some nodejs applications which are at the moment in a stable state (change of specs is not frequent). I would like now to cover the critical parts of my code with tests.
Do you have suggestions/experiences to share?

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow should generally be related to specific programming problems, where you can specify what you're trying to do and what you've tried with concrete examples. Your question at the moment is very open-ended and will attract mostly personal opinions about "how you could potentially do x and y". I recommend that you search around (Google is a good place to start) for what you're interested in, and if you encounter a specific problem trying to implement something, come back and ask a new question about that.

Comment: These are some questions from StackOverflow which demonstrate the exact opposite: "Best practice: escape, or encodeURI / encodeURIComponent", "Best practices for API versioning? [closed]", "Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling"... I culd continue indefinetely!

Comment: You will notice that the first of those questions asks about comparing two functions, and the answers address the merits of each. The third asks about a specific function and demonstrates a reasonable amount of research prior to asking the question. The second is closed as opinion-based, which is the same as I have voted to close your question. My view remains that your question, in its current form, does not ask a specific question and would be entirely opinion based.

Comment: You say opinion based while I ask experience based and StackOverflow is ment to help experience sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha+Chai+SuperTest will be the best option for writing code in NodeJs
http://developmentnow.com/2015/02/05/make-your-node-js-api-bulletproof-how-to-test-with-mocha-chai-and-supertest/

If you want to use any code coverage tool then Istanbul will be best to work with these modules